# DataContractJsonSerializer parse boolean string

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, parsing, boolean

I'm working on a wp7 app and I have a function that sends an http web request to the server and the server returns a json string as a response. Suppose the string is like this:

```
{"products" : 
[
{"PRODUCT_ID" : "1", "PRODUCT_NAME" : "product1","IS_PAID" : "F"},
{"PRODUCT_ID" : "30","PRODUCT_NAME" : "product2","IS_PAID" : "T"},
{"PRODUCT_ID" : "36","PRODUCT_NAME" : "product3","IS_PAID" : "F"}
]}
```

and my product class is like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Product
{        
    [DataMember(Name = "PRODUCT_ID")]
    public long productId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "PRODUCT_NAME")]
    public string productName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "IS_PAID")]
    public bool isPaid { get; set; }
}
```

in my code, when I'm trying to parse the json response:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serailizer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Product[]));
MemoryStream reader = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString));
SynchronizeResponse mResponseObject = (Product[])serailizer.ReadObject(reader);
```

I get an exception:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type MyNameSpance.Product. FormatException

After a lot of debugging I found out that the problem is in the boolean attribute "isPaid" and that the value must be "True" or "False"; not "T" and "F". But I can't change the server response so what can I do? Any ideas ?

Comment: One quick and dirty solution is to replace all instances of "IS_PAID" : "F" to "IS_PAID" : "false". Another would be to deserialize into string field called isPaidRaw and then you have another property named IsPaid of boolean type in which you check the isPaidRaw and convert to bool accordingly.

Comment: I've thought about the second suggestion but I think it may slower the performance and make it look ugly cz I have several boolean fields not just this one so this means a lot of extra attributes to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, "T" is not a valid value for a `bool`.

So, the answer is: don't *use* a `bool`. Use a string instead.

```
[DataMember(Name = "IS_PAID")]
public string isPaidString { get; set; }

public bool isPaid
{
    get {return isPaidString == "T";}
    set {isPaidString = value ? "T" : "F";}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shsould consider using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)